# How To Align Boxes like a Staircase in React and React Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve the desired effect as shown in the image below using react and react bootstrap.

The cards should be positioned like a staircase starting from the left of the screen all the way to the right of the screen. A variable number of cards can be added, and the cards should automatically adjust their spacing evenly.

I am also not sure how to create the hexagons and have them be attached to the cards as shown. The hexagons should act as a mask for images.

[image: Desired Outcome]